# How can I open Uipageview controller view from my table view cell

Tags: tableview

My source code [www.point-star.net/projects/ios_download/page.zip](http://www.point-star.net/projects/ios_download/page.zip) .

Please click on book 2 .You can view the `UITableviewCell` .I need to open my page view controller pages from these tableview cells.

Page view is working->please check on book1 link in app. Thanks

Comment: When I load and look at your app in the simulator, I just see a Google web page.

Comment: please skip that page using below Skip button

Comment: Please don't add your source code as a zip, but rather as a paste or GitHub link in order to prevent it from being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to run your code. Maybe you need to implement `didSelectRow`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self presentViewController:YourSecondViewController animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"View Presented!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question try to push the data from the arrayselected to array at index to another instance of dictionary in the following viewcontroller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // if you want to use the current value of row
    dictionaryforanotherview = [Arrayinthisview objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //get that show detail controller going
    mypageviewcontroller *hola = [[mypageviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"mypageviewcontroller" bundle:[UtilityQVC resourceBundle]];
    [thisviewcontroller.navigationController pushViewController:hola animated:YES];
}
```